# Identify unique values from 2 rows

Tags: sql-server

There can be multiple account names assigned to 1 account number. Since there are a million of rows in the DB I want to find out how I can query the account # that is only assigned to 1 account. Please see sample data below:

Account #        100, 100, 500, 650, 250, 250, 600, 400, 400
Account Name     ABA, DSA, ABA, DSA, ABA, DSA, DSA, ABA, ABA

The result of the query should be account # 500,650,400 because these account # only have one account name assigned to it.

Account 100 and 250 have multiple account names assigned to it. How do I filter account number with only 1 account name assigned to it? Please help

Comment: Look up GROUP BY and HAVING in bol.

Comment: How is your data structured?  Since you have a many-to-many relationship...do you have 1 table for AcctNum, 1 table for AcctName, and a middle lookup table to match these?

Comment: unfortunately this is just one table containing all account # and account names. can anyone show me a sample syntax?

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) is the way to go as stated in a comment above.

```
select account_num
from your_table
group by account_num
having COUNT(*) = 1
```

Some people will frown on the * in COUNT(), but if this is an ad hoc, non-production query, I don't think it's a big deal in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I believe the query should return 400,500,600,650.

Using a query with the clause of `having count(*) =1` would not return 400 based on the data given in the question.

```sql
create table #Accounts (
  AccountNumber int not null
  , AccountName char(3) not null
  )

insert into #Accounts (AccountNumber,AccountName) values
  (100,'ABA')
 ,(100,'DSA')
 ,(500,'ABA')
 ,(650,'DSA')
 ,(250,'ABA')
 ,(250,'DSA')
 ,(600,'DSA')
 ,(400,'ABA')
 ,(400,'ABA');

with cte as (
select AccountNumber
     , AccountName 
     , RowNumber= row_number() over (
        partition by AccountNumber 
        order by AccountName
        )
  from #Accounts 
  group by AccountNumber, AccountName
)
  select AccountNumber
       , AccountName 
    from cte
    where not exists (
      select 1 
        from cte as i 
        where i.AccountNumber = cte.AccountNumber 
          and i.RowNumber = 2
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the account no and name where the account no is linked to more than one name
NOTE: In your example data, account no 400 is linked to the same name twice...
I'm not sure it that should count as linked to 1 name or not...

This will include AccountNo 400

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountNo, AccountName
FROM #Accounts a
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AccountName)
FROM #Accounts b
WHERE a.AccountNo = b.AccountNo) = 1
```

This will NOT include Account No 400 (No DISTINCT in Sub Query)

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountNo, AccountName
FROM #Accounts a
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT(AccountName)
FROM #Accounts b
WHERE a.AccountNo = b.AccountNo) = 1
```